# Violating Same-Origin policy from the Listener context of a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, same-origin-policy

I'm writing an extension to scrape some data off of some internal pages and make a report for it. I have a background listener for my Chrome extension that is attempting to create an iframe and add it to the document.body for the background page. I know I can make a content script and pass the data I need with Chrome's messaging API, I have that working, but I was hoping to find a better solution.

Is it possible to allow access to the DOM within that iframe without a hacky solution such as changing launch options?

Comment: If you want cross-origin access to iframe DOM, I doubt there's a hack around it via the command line switches, but here's the list anyway: https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: There is a switch disable same-origin but I don't want to just always have security disabled in my browser. I'm specifically looking for a solution that doesn't require changing launch options.

Comment: There won't be such a solution I think because it goes against everything the web standards try to accomplish regarding security.

Comment: That's what I was expecting, was just hoping someone knew a workaround.